# Debug service http.get can't connect to api. Getting 'Http failure response for 'https://localhost:55555/api/MyAPI: 0 Unknown Error'

Tags: angular

I am learning Angular and using version 11. I written an API and got the `HttpGet` working with swagger, fiddler, and even chrome by typing the `https://localhost:55555/api/MyAPI.` I followed the tutorial on `https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6` and debug at the `http.get` call, after stepping over, nothing happens. API is up and never breaks.

After I debugged and hit continued, the following error shows up in my console output

Error HttpErrorResponse{headers: HttpHeaders, status:0, statusTExt: 'Unknown Error', url: 'https://localhost:55555/api/MyAPI', ok: false, ...}

message: 'Http failure responswe for 'https://localhost:55555/api/MyAPI: 0 Unknown Error'
name: HttpErrorResponse

I hovered over the object and it only shows the following

```
_isScalar: false
operator: MapOperator ...
source: Observable
__proto__: Object
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

in my component code
export class MyComponent {

```
constructor(private myService: MyService) {
    myService.getApiData().subscribe((result) => {
      let test = result; // never breaks here
      console.log(result);
    });
}

}
```

My code so far is

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operator';
import { MyModel } from './../models/my-model.model';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyService {
  
  private url = 'https://localhost:55555/api/MyAPI';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

  getApiData(): Observable<MyModel> {
     
    return this.http.get<MyModel>(this.url);
  }
}
```

In my `app.module.ts`

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
   HttpClientModule,
  ],
})
```

Comment: How are you calling/using `getApiData`?

Comment: Please post more of your component code, including the constructor and however you are calling the service. Is there a reason your app.module.js is so empty? Is the component you are calling the service from declared in another Module?

Answer (score 0):

You are might not be calling .subscribe() or an equivalent on getApiData(). Or, the issue could be in your API, and adding an error handling function using rxjs on the observable response may give you some clues.

Something like:

```
getDataFn(): void {
  this.myservice.getApidata().subscribe((result) => {
    let test = result; // Check value of "result" of the API call here
  });
}
```

With Angular in this use case, you will not actually call the API until you subscribe.

Also, try changing the return type of getApiData() to HttpResponse, and also add a generic error handler, as it seems like the issue could be your API. like so:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from "rxjs";
import { catchError, tap } from "rxjs/operators";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})

export class MyService {
  private url = 'https://localhost:55555/api/MyAPI';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

  getApiData(): Observable<HttpResponse<MyModel>> {     
    return this.http.get<MyModel>(this.url, { observe: "response" })
            .pipe(
              tap((_) => console.log("called getApiData")),
              catchError(this.handleError<HttpResponse<MyModel>>("getApiData")
            )
          );
  }

  /**
   * Handle Http operation that failed.
   * Let the app continue.
   * @param operation - name of the operation that failed
   * @param result - optional value to return as the observable result
   */
  private handleError<T>(operation = "operation", result?: T) {
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {
      console.error(error); // log to console instead
      console.log(`${operation} failed: ${error.message}`);
      // Let the app keep running by returning an empty result.
      return of(result as T);
    };
  }
}
```

The above code will also log to the console when the observable response is subscribed to in the component. If you use the above code, you will want to look for:

```
result.body
```

Instead of

```
result
```

To get the JSON values from the API response in your component subscription:

```
getDataFn(): void {
  this.myservice.getApidata().subscribe((result) => {
    let test = result.body; // Check value of "result" of the API call here
  });
}
```

EDIT: From your comments below, it appears that the issue may be with your API, not the Angular code.

Comment: thanks but that did not work. Still did not connect to api

Comment: I see your component code, but it doesn't show how you are calling the method in MyService. Is that code block in your ngOnInit? Does it fire on a button click? We need more information. Are you getting any errors in your browser console?

Comment: added it, the calls is from the component constructor and I can break and step thru.

Comment: Are you not using "this" when you call myService? How about any errors in your browser console? try ngOnInit as well, instead of the constructor.

Comment: does not break on ngOnit() and using this.

Comment: seems like httpClient is not working, registered in appmodule.ts but not sure what step I am  missing

Comment: Alright, are you seeing any errors in your browser console? What Module is the component declared in? I don't see it declared in your app.module.ts code. What breakpoint ARE you able to hit?

Comment: 'Http failure responswe for 'https://localhost:55555/api/MyAPI: 0 Unknown Error'

Comment: That sounds like an issue with your API, not your angular code. If the browser is outputting that, it means the API is being called from what I can tell. You may want to shift focus over to your API.